# Azure Microsoft Standard CDN does not purge custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I haven't had any problems until today about purging the CDN, however, today although I have tried to purge it at least 15 times, it never updated the cache in the custom domain. Please note that the other endpoints were updated successfully and served the correct content.

I tried to purge all the content from the endpoint. I've used the web interface to execute the 'purge all' action. The said custom domain is registered via the CDN interface, basically just another endpoint.

I compare the i18n files returned by the custom domain vs Endpoint hostname and origin hostname, which the latter two are identical except the custom domain endpoint.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless this is a published outage or bug, your question has no details to help you. What is a custom domain? What command did you use to purge the CDN? By what method are you determining that the CDN is not purging?

Comment: Tried to add the said details, I use web interface to execute everything.